# Custom formHelper button with icon

Tags: cakephp, button, icons

I'm trying to do a button with a icon tag inside it using cakephp formHelper how do i do that? Here is the final result im looking for:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove this user">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</button>
```

I sort of tryied various alternatives to this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->button(
         $this->Html->tag(
                  'span',
                  null, 
                  array(
                         'class' => 'fa fa-sign-out fa-fw'
                  )
         ), 
         'Remove user', 
         array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'), 
         'type' => 'button'); 
?>
```

i tryied this based on the HtmlHelper::link method from cakephp docs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

It outputs the button with all options and the  tag inside it but the html dont recognizes the inside tag and outputs it as plain text.

Comment: You can just use the exact html you've put in the question - alternatively what did you try, what did it output?

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to put a 'escape' => false parameter to the options array of the tag method for escaping the inner html content:

```
<?php 
     echo $this->Form->button(
          $this->Html->tag(
               'span',
               '', 
               array(
                     'class' => 'fa fa-sign-out fa-fw'
               )
          ), 
          'Remove user', 
          array(
              'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
              'escape' => false
          )
?>
```